# TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of null when PUT-ing in swift

Tags: node.js, swift

I'm trying to PUT in some data to a small node server I've written.

The code on the server side is as follows:

```
router.route('/returnLockID').put(function(req, res){
mongoOp.findOne({
   name: req.body.name
}, function(err, user) {    if(err) {
    response = {"error" : true,"message" : "Error fetching data"};
} else {
// we got data from Mongo.
// change it accordingly.
    if(req.body.LockID !== undefined) {
        // case where ID needs to be updated.
        user.LockID = req.body.LockID;
    }
  //  save the data
    user.save(function(err){
        if(err) {
            response = {"error" : true,"message" : "Error updating data"};
        } else {
            response = {"error" : false,"message" : "Data is updated for "+req.body.name};
        }
        res.json(response);
    })
}
});
    })
```

It all goes through fine when I PUT using postman, i can save, however, when I try PUT from an iOS simulator in swift I get Error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of null
>           at /Users/NikhilVedi/Documents/FYP/Server/lockserver/routes/users.js:92:13
>           at Query. (/Users/NikhilVedi/Documents/FYP/Server/lockserver/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3407:16)
>           at /Users/NikhilVedi/Documents/FYP/Server/lockserver/node_modules/kareem/index.js:259:21
>           at /Users/NikhilVedi/Documents/FYP/Server/lockserver/node_modules/kareem/index.js:127:16
>           at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
>           at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

The swift code is:

```
   @IBAction func setup(_ sender: Any) {

        if (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userIP") == nil)
        {
            //make this a message box and stop the program crashing by assigning user defaults a value
            UserDefaults.standard.set("localhost", forKey: "userIP")

            print("Local host programatically set");
        }

        let u = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userIP")!
        let name = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "email")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://\(u):3000/users/returnLockID")!)
        request.httpMethod = "PUT"
        let postString = "LockID=\(LockID.text!)name=\(name)"
        print(postString)
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            // print("responseString = \(responseString)")

            if let data = responseString?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                let resString = JSON(data: data)

                if resString["success"].stringValue == "true"
                {
                    print("works");

                }
                else if resString["success"].stringValue == "false"
                {
                    print("failed")
                    print(resString["message"].stringValue)
                    //dismiss window and set bool to true
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "LockIDPresent")
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
                }

            }

        }
    task.resume()
           }
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong with the request? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The `user` object in your server code is null - it's not likely this is a problem in Swift. I would use a tool to check the url you're POST'ing, like for instance [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com) - and compare that with the request you're creating with Postman, to find the source of your error.

Answer (score 0):

How is your middleware for the parsing the `body` in express configured?

Looks to me that when you send from **Swift** `lockId` and `name` values, `req.body` is not parsed with the values you are sending.

```
router.route('/returnLockID').put(function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body.name) // null
  // remaining code
}
```

I've accomplished your scenario with a basic example that runs without any problem.

## Node.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.put('/returnLockID', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.name) // Wilson

  res.send({})
});

// remaining code
```

---

## Swift:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:5000/returnLockID")!
let dictionary = ["name": "Wilson"]
let body = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options: [])

if let body = body {

  var request = URLRequest(url: url)
  request.httpMethod = "PUT"
  request.httpBody = body
  request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
  
  let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, err) in
    
    if let error = err {
      print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    guard
      let data = data,
      let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
      else { return }
    
    print("json: \(json)")
    
    
  }
  
  task.resume()
  
}
```